# Bug in BST delete method?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I think there's a bug in this code. I've constructed two different BST's and performed the delete method on both. One worked and the other did not.

```
public void delete(int data) {
    root = delete(root, data);
}

private Node delete(Node node, int data) {
    if(node == null)    throw new IllegalStateException("Empty BST. Cannot delete.");

    if(data < node.data) {
        delete(node.left, data);
    }
    else if(data > node.data) {
        delete(node.right, data);
    }
    else {
        if(node.left == null)
            return node.right;
        else if(node.right == null)
            return node.left;
        else {
            // getting data from the rightmost node in the left subtree
            // because its greater than all the elements the left subtree of the deleted node
            // and smaller than all the elements in the right subtree of the deleted node
            node.data = retrieveData(node.left);
            // delete the rightmost node in the left subtree
            node.left = delete(node.left, node.data);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

private int retrieveData(Node node) {
    while(node.right != null)
        node = node.right;
    return node.data;
}
```

The code in main

```
    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree(5, 2, 12, -4, 3, 9, 21, 19, 25);
    System.out.println(bst.levelOrder());
    bst.delete(12);
    System.out.println(bst.levelOrder());

    bst = new BinarySearchTree(4, 2, 6, -1, 8, 7);
    System.out.println(bst.levelOrder());
    bst.delete(6);
    System.out.println(bst.levelOrder());
```

outputs

```
[5, 2, 12, -4, 3, 9, 21, 19, 25]
[5, 2, 9, -4, 3, 21, 19, 25]
[4, 2, 6, -1, 8, 7]
[4, 2, 6, -1, 8, 7]
```

The Node(12) has been deleted the BST maintains its structure.
The Node(6) has not been deleted however.

Comment: Hint: I suggest you document what your `delete` method is meant to return. That will help you work out whether or not you should be using the return value of your first two recursive calls...

Comment: Poof .. now it works. Another odd thing is that it puts Node(8) in the position of the deleted node instead of Node(7). I know it works both ways but shouldn't it get the rightmost data of the left subtree of Node(6) which is only Node(7) and put it there. it's [4, 2, 8, -1, 7] instead of [4, 2, 7, -1, 8]

Comment: If you've solved your current problem, I suggest you delete this question - or answer it yourself. If you have another problem, create a new question for that.